# Reviewer Stats showing wrong count

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, information-display

I have totally reviewed 716 suggested edits, but it shows I've approved 486 suggestions and rejected 228.

[image]

I searched about it on meta. But, can't get solution. I thought that some of my reviewed posts might get deleted. So, I went to the review history and found [many](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2631434) [of the](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2839160) [posts that](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2479114) [I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2479179) [were](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2556916) [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2525160).

It should be a bug.

Answer (score 6):

Those stats are completely accurate, they're just missing one possible action: **Edit** (aka Improve).

When you opt to improve a suggested edit, Community gets recorded as the user who approves or rejects the edit. You only get recorded for an Edit action so that you get credit for the review. So after you complete your first Edit action, Approves + Rejects != TotalActions anymore.

I'm pretty sure there was a feature-request around here somewhere to add the third type to the stats, but I can't find it at the moment.